# How does one find the specific 'arranged object', NSArray being transformed in an NSValueTransformer?

Tags: objective-c

Using bindings on an `NSArrayController`, I have a working `NSValueTransformer` for an `NSDate` from a controller array record to one column in a table. This displays a formatted date quite nicely.

However, I would like to alter the format based upon the value of another object in the same array from which the `value` is derived.

The code at issue is:  `- (id)transformedValue:(id)value { }`.

I cannot see how to obtain the controller array record from which the `value` is derived.

When I breakpoint on the code, it doesn't show the controller record where the `value` comes from, only the value object itself.

Any help on how to do this?

Comment: Is this the value binding of a text field to `objectValue.someProperty` of the cell view? Do you want to get `objectValue` or do you want to get another object in `arrangedObjects` (= another row)?

Comment: At this point, I have tried every option that I could test and nothing appears to allow one to access the controller array record from which the value is passed.  I did note one possibility, but that seems to be inaccessible at this point; that possibility is shown on a breakpoint in Xcode on the value statements.  Before that is an 'NSBinder' statement, which when clicked on, appears to access the controller array record.  However, I cannot find any Apple documentation which allows a programmer to use that statement.  I can get the controller array record by other means and have.

Comment: Which binding to you use and which object do you want to get?